# How to set resolution of a Java app/the system resolution in fullscreen exclusive mode?

Tags: java, fullscreen

If anyone can point me in the right direction.
Here is the code I have so far.

```
//UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setUndecorated(true);//To remove the bars around the frame.
frame.setResizable(false);//resizability causes unsafe operations.

frame.validate();

//actually applies the fullscreen.
GaphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three complex example you may interested in oracle tutorials.

> Do you want to use high-performance
>   graphics in the Java development
>   environment? Have you always wanted to
>   program a game, but your images
>   wouldn't move fast enough? Has your
>   slide show program not worked properly
>   because you had no control over the
>   user's display resolution? If you've
>   been asking any of these questions,
>   then the full-screen exclusive mode
>   API, introduced in release 1.4, may be
>   what you're looking for.

---

> [CapabilitiesTest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/example-1dot4/CapabilitiesTest.java) demonstrates the different buffering capabilities
>   available for the machine on which it
>   is run.

---

> [DisplayModeTest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/example-1dot4/DisplayModeTest.java) shows a Swing application that uses passive
>   rendering. If full-screen exclusive
>   mode is available, it will enter
>   full-screen exclusive mode. If display
>   mode changes are allowed, it allows
>   you to switch between display modes.

---

> [MultiBufferTest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/example-1dot4/MultiBufferTest.java) enters full-screen mode and uses multi-buffering through an active render loop.

Take a look at this:
[oracle.com/tutorial/fullscreen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html)

and this:
[oracle.com/tutorial/fullscreen/example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/example.html)

### EDIT:

Here is a sample app does what you want:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class DisplayModeChanger extends JFrame {

    private GraphicsDevice device;
    private static JButton changeDM = new JButton("800X600 @ 32 BIT 60HZ");
    private boolean isFullScreenSupported = false;

    public DisplayModeChanger(final GraphicsDevice device) {

        this.device = device;

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        changeDM.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60);
                device.setDisplayMode(dm);
                setSize(new Dimension(dm.getWidth(), dm.getHeight()));
                validate();
            }
        });

    }

    public void goFullScreen() {
        isFullScreenSupported = device.isFullScreenSupported();
        setUndecorated(isFullScreenSupported);
        setResizable(!isFullScreenSupported);
        if (isFullScreenSupported) {
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            validate();
        } else {
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        DisplayModeChanger changer = new DisplayModeChanger(defaultScreen);
        changer.getContentPane().add(changeDM);
        changer.goFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no mentions of resolution. I have a fullscreen app but cannot find how to change the resolution.

Comment: if you need to change systems resolution please mention it in your question. I'll edit my question according to resolution change scenario.

Comment: I just need to change the resolution of the app's display mode I think, not the system.

Comment: my sample code changes systems screen resolution. I don't know what you mean by `resolution of the app's display mode`. try it and let me know if it works. thanks.

Comment: You've been a great help krmby! Thank you! It's the display mode class I was looking for.